# Group by column and get mean of the the group pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below

```
Mode   Time
Air    2
Sea    4
Air    5
Sea    6
```

So I want to have the output as

```
Mode   Time 
Air    3.5
Sea    5
```

The output should contain two columns Mode and the Time.

With my Code I dont see the columns coming. Below is my code:

```
mean_remaining_shipment_time_mode=training_data.groupby('mode')['Time'].mean()
```

The output of this is:

```
Series: mode
Air        3.813711
Ocean     14.670060
Parcel     3.036790
Truck      3.097268
Name: remainingShiptime, dtype: float64
```

Comment: just reset the index to turn that into a dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't select the column:

```
>>> df1.groupby('Mode').mean()
      Time
Mode      
Air    3.5
Sea    5.0
>>>
```

### Edit in response to comment

```
>>> df1.groupby('Mode').mean().reset_index()
  Mode  Time
0  Air   3.5
1  Sea   5.0
>>>
```

Comment: no this would give only one column time ..I need two columns,first is the Mode and second column the Mean time

Comment: call reset_index()

Comment: @asj177 Then you need to reset the index. The result of a groupby aggregation will be indexed by the grouping arguments. See the edit.

Comment: yes got it ..reset_index() call did the work ..Thank u